# Big differences in image filtered with rotated Gabor kernels

Tags: opencv, image-processing, pattern-matching, computer-vision, object-recognition

I have calculated 8 Gabor filters with Theta rotation m*PI/8.

Parameters of the Gabor kernel given as input to OpenCv cv2.getGaborKernel:
ksize = 11, theta = m*PI/8    lambd = 16/3    sigma = (5.09030 * 8.0) / (3.0 * PI)    gamma = 0.5890 psi = 0

```
kernel = cv2.getGaborKernel(ksize = (ksize,ksize), sigma = sigma, 
               theta = theta, lambd = lambd, 
                               gamma = gamma, psi = psi)
```

The parameters are designed according to "Features Extraction using a Gabor filter family", Zhen, Zhao, Wang.
The formula adopted is the one of the third family of Gabor filters.

The 8 filters obtained are:

[image: Obtained Gabor filters]

The original image is:

[image]

The images obtained by filtering the images are:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

They are calculated with cv2.filter2D

```
fimg = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_64F, kernel)
```

Why the gabor filters with theta = 0 and theta = PI / 2.0 have a really different continuous component compared to the others?
It does not really make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was the PSI param that I set to 0. The problem is immediatly fixed is psi is kept at the default value PI/2.

Comment: would you please take a look at my question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218236/cluster-texture-based-on-features-extracted-from-gabor